# Parametrized join in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, left-join

I am doing manual `join` and I need to pass a parameter to its `ON` clause:

```
Foo.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN bars ON foos.id = bars.foo_id AND bars.baz = #{baz}")
```

Is there a way to pass `baz` as a parameter, to avoid potential injection problems? There is a method `sanitize_sql_array`, but I'm not sure how to make use of it in this case.

Note: I can't use `where` because it's not the same.

Comment: so baz is another joined model? Can you give me the value you have for baz?

Comment: Yep, that would be great to know what baz may be.

Comment: `baz` is a variable holding a string literal or a number, for example. It's not another model, it's a value I want to pass to ON condition in outer join.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With sanitize_sql_array, that would be:

```
# Warning: sanitize_sql_array is a protected class method, be aware of that to properly use it in your code
ar = ["LEFT OUTER JOIN bars ON foos.id = bars.foo_id AND bars.baz = %s", baz]

# Within a class method in foo model:
sanitized_sql = sanitize_sql_array(ar)
Foo.joins(sanitized_sql)
```

Tried it and it worked.

Comment: Note, I had to access `sanitize_sql_array` on my model class, like `Foo.sanitize_sql_array`.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter: could you add the rails version you are using?

Comment: Rails 5.2. Maybe it's directly accessible in newer versions?

Comment: I'd say the other way around: it was directly accessible in older versions ^^' 
But, do note that I used the "sanitize_sql_array" within a model. I don't recall if I put it in a class method when I tested...

Comment: Very interesting. You've now piqued my interest so I tested it quickly and your hunch is correct. Because it's a _class_ method, it's available in a _class_ method just by calling `sanitize_sql_array`, but when used in an _instance_ method, you need to call it from the _class_, like `Foo.sanitize_sql_array`. Thanks for clarifying this for myself and others. :)

Comment: @JoshuaPinter thanks for your test, I've just edited my answer with that clarification ^^'

Comment: If you need to invoke it from somewhere outside of your model you can access it through the `ActiveRecord::Base` class:
`ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize_sql_array(['INNER JOIN foo on bar = ?', 123])`

Answer (score 13):

Active record models have [`sanitize`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4e80c12de3058eafd6c4f209bc78d9e3f6e26a0f/activerecord/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb#L6-L10) class method, so you could do:

```
Foo.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN bars ON foos.id = bars.foo_id AND bars.baz = #{Foo.sanitize(baz)}")
```

__

It's been removed starting rails 5.1, use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote()` instead

Comment: For more recent viewers, this method does not work any more as `sanitize` was not part of the public API and was removed in Rails 5.1 ( see discussion and workaround at https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28947).

Answer (score 2):

Arel can do it.

```
baz = "i am a baz"
foos = Arel::Table.new('foos') # or Foo.arel_table, if this is an AR model
bars = Arel::Table.new('bars')
join = foos.outer_join(bars).on(
  foos[:id].eq(bars[:foo_id]),
  bars[:baz].eq(baz))
puts join.to_sql
```

This produces

```sql
SELECT FROM "foos"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "bars" ON
  "foos"."id" = "bars"."foo_id"
  AND "bars"."baz" = 'i am a baz'
```

Now if you want to get that back into an ActiveRecord query and not just print the SQL:

```
Foo.joins(join.join_sources)
```

Comment: That should be the answer.  Use `Foo.arel_table` to not have table names in code.

Answer (score -4):

I think you should try like this:

```
Foo.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN bars ON foo.id = bars.foo_id AND bars.baz = ?", baz)
```

With more parameters:

```
Foo.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN bars ON foo.id = ? AND bars.baz = ? AND ...", foo, baz, etc...)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. `baz` is not interpreted as a parameter value, but as another joined model. You can try it yourself. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9b67cb3d394692aa7feb7510aab0871e557d3dd0/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L1036

Comment: AFAIK Rails (even at 4.0) does not support parameters in a `JOIN` clause. One has to generate the SQL statement oneself, as Mladen concluded. I think [@Kulgar has it right](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35744285/712765) for how to do that safely.

Comment: are you sure that baz is passed as a string literal or an integer and not an another AR object?

Answer (score -5):

You should be safe if you pass a hash of values, AR will protect you against SQL injections, like this:

```
Foo.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN bars ON foo.id = bars.foo_id").where(bars: {baz: baz})
```

Just don not use row strings in sql that are vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: Unfortunately, not what I want. The condition in WHERE is not equivalent to the condition in ON.

Comment: Because of the outer join, having the condition in the `JOIN` clause is different than having the condition of the `WHERE` clause. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c827b7/5