# Parameterize an ActiveRecord #joins method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am refactoring a fairly complex query that involves chaining multiple `.joins` methods together. In one of these joins I am using a raw SQL query which uses string interpolation i.e joining `WHERE foo.id = #{id}`. I am aware that I can parameterize ActiveRecord `#where` by using the `?` variable and passing in the arguments as parameters, but the joins method does not support multiple arguments in this fashion. For example:

Using:

`Post.my_scope_name.joins("LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.id = images.post_id and posts.id = ?", "1")` in order to pass in an id of `1` produces an `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid`

because the generated SQL looks like this:

`"LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.id = images.post_id and posts.id = ? 1"`

What is the standard approach to parameterizing queries when using the `joins` method?

Comment: `joins` does support multiple arguments. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-multiple-associations

Comment: Can you please show what you are trying to do in a code like fashion rather than just explaining it in words? You can build these types of joins using `Arel::Nodes::InnerJoin` or `Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin` but with out context I would prefer to not answer directly

Comment: @engineersmnky I updated the post with an example

Comment: @Glyoko while it does support multiple arguments it does not naturally support multiple join conditions e.g. "posts.id = images.post_id AND posts.id = 1"

Comment: `posts.id = 1` shouldn't be done with a joins. You should use `where(id: 1)` for that, in conjunction with a `joins`. eg `Post.some_other_scope.joins(:images).where(id: 1)`

Comment: Maybe you can use `sanitize_sql_array` similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/35744285/8200155?

Answer (score 4):

[`arel`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/arel) "A Relational Algebra" is the underlying query assembler for Rails and can be used to construct queries, conditions, joins, CTEs, etc. that are not high level supported in Rails. Since this library is an integral part of Rails most Rails query methods will support direct injection of `Arel` objects without issue (to be honest most methods convert your arguments into one of these objects anyway).

In your case you can construct the join you want as follows:

```
  posts_table = Post.arel_table
  images_table = Image.arel_table 
  some_id = 1

  post_join = Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin.new(
    posts_table,
    Arel::Nodes::On.new(
      posts_table[:id].eq(images_table[:post_id])
        .and(posts_table[:id].eq(some_id))
    )
  )
```

SQL produced:

```
  post_join.to_sql
  #=> "LEFT OUTER JOIN [posts] ON [posts].[id] = [images].[post_id] AND [posts].[id] = 1"
```

Then you just add this join to your current query

```
  Image.joins(post_join)
  #=> SELECT images.* FROM images LEFT OUTER JOIN [posts] ON [posts].[id] = [images].[post_id] AND [posts].[id] = 1
```